How can i write this strcat function without getting exit code 139 and segfault?
I'm trying to write the following c code in order to make my own mystrcat() function (similar to the strcat() found in <string.h>) that concatenates 2 strings together.
When I run the following code though:
#include <stdio.h>

void mystrcat(char * str1, char * str2, char * str3){
    int i = 0;
    //loop through chars of str1 and add them to str3
    while (str1[i] != '\0'){
        str3[i] = str1[i];
        i++;
    }
    int j = 0;
    //loop through chars of str2 and add them to str3 after str1
    while (str2[j] != '\0'){
        str3[i + j] = str2[j];
        j++;
    }
    //add null byte as last char of str3
    str3[i + j] = '\0';
}

int main(){
    //init strings
    char *str1, *str2, *str3;
    //get strings from stdin
    scanf("%s %s", str1, str2);

    mystrcat(str1, str2, str3);

    printf("%s\n", str3);
    return 0;
}

I am only able to input the first string, then after hitting enter to input the second one I get segmentation fault (and echo $? gives exit code: 139). I don't understand why this solution is not working or what should be done about it. I have also tried slightly altering the function so that str3 is declared in the global static memory like this:
char * mystrcat(char * str1, char * str2){
    static char * str3;
    int i = 0;
    //loop through chars of str1 and add them to str3
    while (str1[i] != '\0'){
        str3[i] = str1[i];
        i++;
    }
    int j = 0;
    //loop through chars of str2 and add them to str3 after str1
    while (str2[j] != '\0'){
        str3[i + j] = str2[j];
        j++;
    }
    //add null byte as last char of str3
    str3[i + j] = '\0';

    return str3;
}

but it's no use, I get the same behavior. All of this compiles perfectly with no warnings by the way.
I have also tried using <stdlib.h>'s malloc function in order to assign str3 to the heap but it still produces exit code 139.

In main none of your pointers point to valid memory. As a result, dereferencing them leads to undefined behavior.
You need to ensure they do point to either automatic duration storage or dynamically allocated storage with sufficient space.
E.g.
int main() {
    char str1[100] = "", str2[100] = "", str3[200] = "";

    scanf("%99s %99s", str1, str2);
    mystrcat(str1, str2, str3);
    printf("%s\n", str3);
}

Your two source strings can be string literals since there's no attempt to modify them, but your destination needs to be a writable character array to avoid undefined behavior.
Once you've addressed this, stick with your first version of mystrcat but consider why you'd want to make a function take two strings to concat to a third when you would normally just call strcat twice.
strcat(str3, str1);
strcat(str3, str2);

Warnings
You've stated that your code compiled with no warnings or errors. You should turn up your warnings. Compiling your first code sample gave me:
$ gcc test3.c -Wall -Wextra
test3.c: In function ‘main’:
test3.c:24:5: warning: ‘str1’ is used uninitialized in this function -Wuninitialized]
     scanf("%s %s", str1, str2);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test3.c:24:5: warning: ‘str2’ is used uninitialized in this function -Wuninitialized]
test3.c:26:5: warning: ‘str3’ is used uninitialized in this function -Wuninitialized]
     mystrcat(str1, str2, str3);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Minor str3[200] = ""; could be str3[199];.

If you compile with GCC or Clang with the -Wall flag on the command line, it actually gives warnings:
test.c:24:20: warning: variable 'str1' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
   24 |     scanf("%s %s", str1, str2);
      |                    ^~~~
test.c:22:15: note: initialize the variable 'str1' to silence this warning
   22 |     char *str1, *str2, *str3;
      |               ^
      |                = NULL
test.c:24:26: warning: variable 'str2' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
   24 |     scanf("%s %s", str1, str2);
      |                          ^~~~
test.c:22:22: note: initialize the variable 'str2' to silence this warning
   22 |     char *str1, *str2, *str3;
      |                      ^
      |                       = NULL
test.c:26:26: warning: variable 'str3' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
   26 |     mystrcat(str1, str2, str3);
      |                          ^~~~
test.c:22:29: note: initialize the variable 'str3' to silence this warning
   22 |     char *str1, *str2, *str3;
      |                             ^
      |                              = NULL

You should probably always compile with -Wall, it gives very great tips.
The problem is that: scanf does not allocate memory for your strings. When you write:
char *str;

what you create is just a pointer, which should reference allocated memory. There is no allocated space for characters.
The simple solution is often to use a fixed size:
char str1[100], str2[100], str3[200];
scanf("%99s %99s", str1, str2);

Writing %99s in scanf’s format string limits the reading to 99 characters, which is the maximum number of characters that the arrays str1 and str2 can store.
If you compile for a POSIX environment, you can use the %ms code to allocate your strings:
char *str1, *str2;
scanf("%ms %ms", &str1, &str2);
char str3[strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1];
mystrcat(str1, str2, str3);
free(str1); free(str2);

When you use %ms, you must pass the address of your pointers to scanf. But with %ms, your code is not portable.
The portable way to read a string of any length is to write your own function:
char *fread_str(FILE *file, char const *terminators)
{
    size_t len = 16, pos = 0;
    char *str = NULL;
    do {
        len *= 2;
        str = realloc(str, len * sizeof(str));
        char format[32];
        sprintf(format, "%%%zu[^%s]", (len - 1) - pos, terminators);
        fscanf(file, format, str + pos);
        pos += strlen(str + pos);
    } while (pos + 1 >= len);
    return str;
}

int main()
{
   printf("%s\n", fread_str(stdin, "\n"));
}

The 139 return code of your program is 128 + 11, which means your program was killed by the signal number 11, which is: segmentation fault. You can see the list of signals with kill -l in your terminal.

m is a modifier which needs to be used with a conversion specifier -- either s, c, or [.  So you need "%ms %ms" as your first argument to scanf.  It is part of the POSIX standard, so is available with any system that supports POSIX, not just GNU libraries.

Is there no way to dynamically assert the amount of memory I want to allocate, depending on the length of the string that is inputted by the user?

@stefanoukios On a POSIX environment, use %ms. On other systems, you should do it in a specialized function containing a loop which reads each time a bunch of character, then increases the allocated size while '\n' is not read.

@stefanoukios For a portable solution, you should write your specialized function containing a loop which reads each time a bunch of character, then increases the allocated size while '\n' or space is not read. I’ve added this function in my answer.
